# does this proof of inequality work when passing in the limit?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to show $x < \frac{\pi}{2} \sin(x)$ for all $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

I know that $x \mapsto \frac{x}{sinx}$ on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ is strictly increasing (proved previously).

So for $x, y \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$

$x < y \implies \frac{x}{sinx} < \frac{y}{siny}$

let $y \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ and we get our result.

Is this reasoning correct? I'm most concerned about when I take the limit, and how that proves it, since I don't know anything about the endpoints.

In particular, would I need continuity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for this to work. Could someone please explain this? (I know that we have it, but is it necessary for this proof)

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you want to show. I mean by definition if $x\in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ then $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$ so $x<\frac{\pi}{2}$. There is nothing to prove.

Comment: Updated @user123234. my mistake

Comment: Your approach is correct. And you indeed have continuity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ since more generally $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\sin(x)}$ is continuous on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: Do I need to state this for my approach to work? @user123234

Comment: I would state it.

Comment: If you are unsure of why $\lim_{y \to \pi/2} \frac y{\sin y} = \frac \pi 2$, then you need to show that it is true. Never rely on just "stating" something you yourself are not confident in your own understanding about.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused on it @PaulSinclair . Is continuity at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the reason I can calculate the limit there?

Comment: No and yes. The function is continuous there because the limit exists and is equal to the function value. If we were not able to show that *without* knowing the function is continuous, then we would have no way of knowing the function is continuous there. But, because continuity of $y$ and $\sin y$ have been proven before, and the product of continuous functions has been proven to be continuous, and because inversion is continuous everywhere the function being inverted is not $0$, we can use these facts to know this function is continuous at $\frac \pi2$ without having to prove it directly.

Comment: I guess what I am confused about is how we can take $y \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ and get our result from that. @PaulSinclair

Comment: @user123234 how can it be continuous at 0 if $sin(x) = 0$ there?

Comment: First of all you don't need continuity at $x=0$ because you take the limit to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But nevertheless, $\frac{x}{\sin(x)}$ is continuous at $x=0$ which can be showed by using L'Hôpital's rule.